# Reverse input program in C99

Tags: beginner, c, io, formatting

I am writing simple program to reverse its input and output the reversed version. I came up with this code. So how can I improve it? Something tells me that `int lengthSoFar` is bad in both `printArray` and `reverse` functions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ARRSIZE 1000

//function declarations...
char *reverse(char *a, int l);

void printArray(char *a, int l);

int main(void) {
    int c = 0;
    int i = 0;
    char buff[ARRSIZE];
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (i > ARRSIZE) printArray(reverse(buff, i), i);
        if (c != '\n') {
            buff[i]=c;
            i++;
        }else{
            printArray(reverse(buff, i), i);
            memset(buff, 0, sizeof buff);
            i=0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

char *reverse(char *array, int lengthSoFar) {
    int i = 0;
    int j = lengthSoFar - 1;
    static char arrayToReturn[ARRSIZE];
    while (i < lengthSoFar && j >= 0) {
        arrayToReturn[i] = array[j];
        i++;
        j--;
    }
    return arrayToReturn;
}

void printArray(char *array, int lengthSoFar) {
    for (int i = 0; i < lengthSoFar; i++) {
        putchar(array[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which C standard do you want to use? ANSI C? C99? C11?

Comment: I use C99 C standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this program reads its input one line at a time, I would naturally expect it to print its output line by line as well.  Instead, **it prints no newlines at all**, which is surprising to me.

---

When dealing with buffers, it is usually beneficial to **test whether the program works as intended with a tiny buffer**.  (Alternatively, you could feed it excessively long input, but reducing the buffer size is easier.)  If I reduce `ARRSIZE` to 10, then give it `hello there` as input, I get repeated output followed by a crash:

```
ereht ollehereht ollehAbort trap: 6
```

So, you have some bugs with the `if (i > ARRSIZE) printArray(reverse(buff, i), i);` logic.  I'll leave it to you to figure out what went wrong.

---

You `memset()` it to 0 after printing, but not initially.  So, it looks like you are under the impression that

> ```
> char buff[ARRSIZE];
> ```

gives you an array whose contents are all initially 0.  However, **zeroed memory is not guaranteed** by the C language specification.  In practice, most modern operating systems will zero all of your memory before your program runs, as a security precaution so that you can't peek at potentially sensitive junk that a previously executed program left behind in memory.  However, to be strictly correct, you would only be guaranteed a blank slate if you wrote one of the following:

```
char buff[ARRSIZE] = { 0 };
char buff[ARRSIZE] = "";
static char buff[ARRSIZE];
```

I don't recommend a `static` buffer for this application.

---

Your `reverse()` function returns a `static` character buffer.  I don't recommend that design for two reasons:

- The buffer size is predetermined, such that it's not a general-purpose string-reversing function that works with any input.
- `static` buffers are error-prone designs.  If you call `char *a = reverse(foo)`, then `char *b = reverse(bar)`, it could surprise you that `a` ends up containing the reversed contents of `bar`.  Such side-effects are undesirable.

Based on the observation that the lengths of the input and output are the same, I would design `reverse()` to accept an ***in-out parameter***.  That is, instead of returning a reversed copy of its input, it just operates on the buffer directly.  Though in-out parameters may feel like an unnatural hack, they are often the best way in C to avoid memory-management headaches.

---

This program is supposed to process one line at a time.  Therefore, **the code would be clearer if it worked a line at a time** rather than a character at a time.  For example, you can read a whole line using `fgets()`, and you can print a whole line using `puts()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ARRSIZE 1000

/* Writes a NUL terminator at the first carriage return or newline
   (if any).  Returns the length of the (likely truncated) string. */
size_t chomp(char *line) {
    size_t len = strcspn(line, "\r\n");
    line[len] = '\0';
    return len;
}

/* Reverses a buffer of len bytes in place.  Returns a pointer to
   the same buffer. */
char *reverse(char *buffer, size_t len) {
    for (char *a = buffer, *b = buffer + len - 1; a < b; a++, b--) {
        char swap = *a;
        *a = *b;
        *b = swap;
    }
    return buffer;
}

int main(void) {
    char line[ARRSIZE];
    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin)) {
        size_t len = chomp(line);
        puts(reverse(line, len));
    }
    return ferror(stdin);
}
```

Comment: Really good explanation :) I just didn't understand`ferror(stdin)`. I don't know what is `ferror` doing.And the `stdin` variable you passed both to `ferror` and to `fgets`.

Comment: And i wanted to ask,is it wrong (or worse) to put main function firstly and then other functions below it.Of course declaring them will be necessary.

Comment: Too much questions i am asking.But i need one more to sleep well :) I wanted to ask what is `strcspn` ?? I googled,but i can't find good explanation

Comment: `stdin` is [standard input](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19540425/1157100) — basically the stream that is associated with keyboard input, but which could also be input from a pipe or a file. It's the same source that `getchar()` would read from. [`ferror(stdin)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/ferror) tests whether any error has occurred while trying to read from `stdin`. [`strcspn(…, "\r\n")`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcspn) finds the number of characters before the first carriage return or newline is encountered.

Comment: It is customary to put `main()` last, so that you don't have to declare all of the functions that it uses.

Answer (score 5):

## Take a destination for the reversed string

Instead of a local pointer, make `reverse` a `void` function:

```
void reverse(char * dst, const char * src, size_t length) {
    for(size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        dst[i] = src[length - i - 1];
    }
}
```

The names `dst` (destination) and `src` (source) and their order stem from standard library functions like `strncpy`.

[`size_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/size_t) is an unsigned integer type, and large enough to index an array that spans your whole memory. We're allowed to define `size_t i` in the `for` loop, therefore our variable doesn't live any longer than necessary.

But you already did that for `printArray`, so I guess you knew that :)

```
void printArray(const char * array, size_t length) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        putchar(array[i]);
    }
}
```

It's good practice to use `const <type> *` if you don't want to change the data by accident.

## Use a function to ask for the string

To keep your `main` sleek and your code more reusable, provide a function to get the string from the user instead:

```
int getInput(char * dst, size_t max_len) {
    int length = 0;
    int c;

    while((c = getchar()) != EOF && length < max_len) {
        if(c == '\n')
            return length;

        dst[length++] = c;
    }
    return c == EOF ? EOF : length;
}
```

This will return `EOF` if `getchar()` returned `EOF`, and the number of read characters otherwise.

## Putting all back together

I omit the functions I've already covered above, but if we use them, we end up with the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ARRSIZE 1000

int getInput(char * dst, size_t max_len);
void reverse(char * dst, const char * src, size_t length);
void printArray(const char * array, size_t length);

int main(void) {
    int length = 0;
    char buff[ARRSIZE];
    char reversed[ARRSIZE];

    while ((length = getInput(buff, ARRSIZE)) != EOF) {
        reverse(buff, reversed, length);
        printArray(reversed, length);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Which, in my opinion, is rather readable. Note that your `memset` wasn't necessary. After all, we're going to overwrite the values in `buff` with the next input.

Comment: I'd consider null terminating your string in `getInput`, you've also got a typo when you call it, I'm guessing it should be `getInput(buff, ARRSIZE)`, not `getInput(dst...`

Comment: @forsvarir Good point on `getInput(dst…`. I would use `\NUL`, but I'm not sure whether OP wants to use the `char[ARRSIZE]` as actual strings. Since there is the `printArray` function, it's possible that `\NUL` is part of the input. Otherwise one could have used `puts(reversed)`.

Comment: Fair enough, just looks a little odd, because of the /n detection

Comment: @forsvarir yeah. Without `\n`, it would be simply `fread(stdin, buff, sizeof char, ARRSIZE - 1)`. Well, more or less.

Comment: Nice Lesson :) Helpful !

Comment: And one part i don't really understand. What is `size_t`  ? And i get compilation errors by the way : `/tmp/ccEXQtNg.o: In function main:
ReverseInput6.c:(.text+0x74): undefined reference to getInput
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: @MuhamedCicak You have to put all functions in your code, not only there declaration. I've omitted them from the final code snippet for brevity: *"I omit the functions I've already covered above, …"*. And I've linked an article on `size_t`. You can think of it as `unsigned int`, `unsigned long int`, or `unsigned long long int`, depending on how much memory your architecture can handle.

Comment: I actually put the functions.I dont know why it wont compile.And thanks for the explanation of size_t.

Answer (score 5):

#### Buffer overflow

There are two problems with your current attempt to prevent buffer overflow:

> ```
>     if (i > ARRSIZE) printArray(reverse(buff, i), i);
> ```

The first is that your code is off by one, and if `i` is larger than `ARRSIZE` you have already overflowed your buffer by one character.  So you should change `>` to `>=`.  The second is that once you detect the overflow, you don't set `i` back to zero.  So you will continue to write past the end of your buffer.